# Are Nouns as Adjective and Present Participle as Adjective in the sentence?

Tags: adjectives, nouns, present-participles, as

> Steve Mnuchin may be the silver bullet to the vampire life-blood cash draining net worth sweep.

source:http://seekingalpha.com/article/4027602-ding-dong-net-worth-sweep-dead-yet.

Let's divide it into tow parts.
Part A :Steve Mnuchin may be the silver bullet to
Part B :the vampire life-blood cash draining net worth sweep

The whole structure is : Somebody is the silver bullet to something.
silver bullet is a idiom in english,the meaning is simple to understand for me.
The something ,part B is confused me.

Can we shorten part B into a word *cash sweep*?
1.  vampire life-blood  is a grammar rule *Noums as Adjective*, the  noun *vampire* and *life-blood*  performs the function of an adjective to modify cash sweep.
2.*cash draining net worth sweep* can shorten as *cash sweep*,*draining net worth* , Present Participle as Adjective, performs the function of an adjective too, to modify  sweep.

Is my analysis for the sentence right?

To think over the whole sententce after reading SthoneyB's explanation,can i rewrite it as below?

> Steve Mnuchin may be the silver bullet to the vampire that net worth sweep drained life-blood cash.

Comment: No: the vampire **is** the net worth sweep.  "SM may be the silver bullet to the vampire NWS, which drains L-BC (from FM and FC)." Your relative clause is ill-formed: *that* should replace the subject, but you provide the subject, NWS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the vampire life-blood cash draining net worth sweep

I suggest you should parse it thus:

- the 'core' of the entire phrase is the NP *net worth sweep* ... this phrase occurs in the title of the article, and repeatedly in the body, and signifies

  > The U.S. government’s 2012 decision to take all the profits from Fannie Mae and Freddie Mac —[*Bloomberg*](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-04-14/fannie-freddie-investors-fight-to-undo-u-s-net-worth-sweep)

  This NP may be paraphrased as "a sweep of net worth". It is parsed as:

  - *sweep*, employed as a noun, the head of the NP phrase, and
  - *net worth*, an attributive NP designating what the sweep sweeps. That in turn has two constituents:

    - *worth*, a noun, the head of the NP, and
    - *net*, an adjective modifying *worth*
- This core nominal has two modifiers:

  - *vampire*, an attributive noun, and
  - *life-blood cash draining*, a 'gloss' on or expansion of *vampire*. It may be parsed as an inverted participle phrase which fronts the participle's object. It thus has two constituents:

    - *draining*, which describes *net worth sweep*, and
    - *life-blood cash*, which is an NP representing what the net worth sweep drains. That in turn has two constituents:

      - *cash*, the head of the phrase, and
      - *life-blood*, an attributive noun modifying *cash*

The entire sentence may be paraphrased

> The government's sweep of Fannie Mae and Freddie Mac's net worth is vampiric, draining the cash which is the life-blood of those institutions. Steve Mnuchin may be the "silver bullet" which slays that vampire.

Comment: To think over the whole sententce after reading SthoneyB's explanation,can i rewrite it as below?

Comment: Steve Mnuchin may be the silver bullet to the vampire  that net worth sweep  drained life-blood cash.